# declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration error in c

Tags: c, function, struct, error-handling

header file:

```
#ifndef MEM_CLEAR_MEMORY_H
#define MEM_CLEAR_MEMORY_H

#pragma once

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../man/signUp/acc.h"
#include "../man/logIn/log.h"

// Fnctions declaration:
void clear(struct info *head);
void delete(struct threadArg* head);

#endif
```

c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "clear_memory.h"

void clear(struct info *head){
    if(head->next == NULL) return;
    clear(head->next);
    free(head);
}

void delete(struct threadArg *head){
    if(head->next == NULL) return;
    delete(head->next);
    free(head);
}
```

the struct declered in log.h file:

```
#ifndef MAN_LOG_H
#define MAN_LOG_H

#pragma once
#pragma pack(1)

#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 256
#define MAX_LINE 10
#define PATH_SIZE 1024
#define FILE_NAME_SIZE 1024
#define EMAIL_SIZE 250
#define PASSWORD_SIZE 50

#include "../signUp/acc.h"
#include "../../mem/clear_memory.h"

// arguments of the thread function
struct threadArg{
    FILE *file_name;
    int line;
    struct threadArg* next;
};

//Functions:
bool log_in();
static bool check(const char *path);
static void set_struct_data(struct threadArg* temp, FILE* file, int line_num);
bool check_account(struct info* temp, char* email, char* password);
static void* read_line(void* arg);

#endif
```

the function check_account inside log.c file:

```
bool check_account(struct info* temp, char* email, char* password){

  char fileName[FILE_NAME_SIZE];

  strcpy(fileName,temp->folder_name);
  strcat(fileName,"/");
  strcat(fileName,email);
  strcat(fileName,".txt");

  if(check(fileName)){
   FILE* check = fopen(fileName,"r");
   char* return1, return2;
   pthread_t email, password;
   
   // if check == NULL means the file has not been open
   if(check == NULL) return false;
   
   struct threadArg* temp1 = (struct threadArg* )malloc(sizeof(struct threadArg));
   struct threadArg* temp2 = (struct threadArg* )malloc(sizeof(struct threadArg));
   // set the data of the 2 member of struct created 
   set_struct_data(temp1, check , 2);
   set_struct_data(temp2, check, 4);

   // create 2 thread functions 
   pthread_create(&email, NULL, &read_line, (void*)temp1);
   pthread_create(&password, NULL, &read_line, (void*)temp2);
   // wait the thread to return the values
   pthread_join(email, (void**)&return1);
   pthread_join(password, (void**)&return2);

   delete(temp1);
   delete(temp2);
   fclose(check);
   return true;
  }
  return false; 
}
```

the error is:

```
In file included from man/logIn/log.h:15,
                 from man/logIn/log.c:7:
man/logIn/../../mem/clear_memory.h:16:20: warning: ‘struct threadArg’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
   16 | void delete(struct threadArg* head);
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
man/logIn/log.c: In function ‘check_account’:
man/logIn/log.c:113:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘delete’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  113 |    delete(temp1);
      |           ^~~~~
      |           |
      |           struct threadArg *
In file included from man/logIn/log.h:15,
                 from man/logIn/log.c:7:
man/logIn/../../mem/clear_memory.h:16:31: note: expected ‘struct threadArg *’ but argument is of type ‘struct threadArg *’
   16 | void delete(struct threadArg* head);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
man/logIn/log.c:114:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘delete’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  114 |    delete(temp2);
      |           ^~~~~
      |           |
      |           struct threadArg *
In file included from man/logIn/log.h:15,
                 from man/logIn/log.c:7:
man/logIn/../../mem/clear_memory.h:16:31: note: expected ‘struct threadArg *’ but argument is of type ‘struct threadArg *’
   16 | void delete(struct threadArg* head);
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
gcc -c mem/clear_memory.c
```

Comment: This error happens when the compiler gets the function prototype or the function itself before it sees the declaration of the type it references. What is the compiler command you're running?

Comment: I use Makefile to compile the it

Comment: Makefiles just automate the compilation process. Read the makefile to see what commands are run

Comment: I found the error it's because the function name

Answer (score 3):

You've got circular includes.

clear_memory.h and log.h both attempt include each other.  As a result, only one will get included in the other.  This is resulting in clear_memory.h not seeing the definitions from log.h.

There's nothing in clear_memory.h that needs to be referenced in log.h, so remove this line from log.h:

```
#include "../../mem/clear_memory.h"
```

Comment: I need to include clear_memory.h in log.h because i call the function delete in log.c line 113 and 114

Comment: @HocineAbderrahmane Which means that log.c needs to include it, *not* log.h.